# Retreiving value of second field of an existing RDD based on value from first field of another RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I have data in three files as below in HDFS

EmployeeManagers.txt (EmpID,ManagerID)

```
1,5
2,4
3,4
4,6
5,6
```

EmployeeNames.txt (EmpID,Name)

```
1,Ronald Rays
2,Jimmy Kent
3,Shannon Witt
4,Krinton Kale
5,Harry Donal
6,Christina Fernandez
```

EmployeeSalary.txt (EmpID,Salary)

```
1,1000
2,2000
3,3000
4,4000
5,5000
6,6000
```

I want to print the data by creating RDDs from these files in the format ID, Employee Name, Salary, Manager Name.

I have joined 3 RDDs based on the key i.e. first column in each text file and able to print the Manager ID but not the manager name.

Here is the code that I've written to do it.

```
val manager = sc.textFile("EmployeeManagers")
val managerRDD = manager.map(x => (x.split(",")(0), x.split(",")(1)))
val name = sc.textFile("EmployeeNames")
val namePairRDD = name.map(x => (x.split(",")(0), x.split(",")(1)))
val salary = sc.textFile("EmployeeSalary")
val salaryPairRDD = salary.map(x => (x.split(",")(0), x.split(",")(1)))
val data = namePair.join(salaryPair).join(managerPair)
```

The current output is something like as shown below

```
scala> data.collect();
res4: Array[(String, ((String, String), String))] = Array((4,((Krinton Kale,4000),6)), (5,((Harry Donal,5000),6)), (2,((Jimmy Kent,2000),4)), (3,((Shannon Witt,3000),4)), (1,((Ronald Rays,1000),5)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you'll have to join on `namePairRDD` *again*, this time with the manager ID as the key:

```
val result = namePairRDD
  .join(salaryPairRDD)
  .join(managerPairRDD)
  .map { case (id, ((name, salary), mngrId)) => (mngrId, (id, name, salary)) }
  .join(namePairRDD) // join again, this time on managerId
  .map { case (_, ((id, name, salary), mngrName)) => (id, name, salary, mngrName) }

result.foreach(println)
// (2,Jimmy Kent,2000.0,Krinton Kale)
// (3,Shannon Witt,3000.0,Krinton Kale)
// (1,Ronald Rays,1000.0,Harry Donal)
// (4,Krinton Kale,4000.0,Christina Fernandez)
// (5,Harry Donal,5000.0,Christina Fernandez)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of using 'case'.